# Using Solr Join to query location

Tags: solr

Here is my data structure:

```
Users (UserName, Location)
UserRecords (RecordId, Username, Category)
```

Example Data

```
Users: 
    (Bob, "38.45,-88.14"), 
    (Alice, "36.11,-87.32"), 
    (Jake, "37.45,-85.02")

UserRecords:
    (1, Bob, Medical), 
    (2, Bob, Contact), 
    (3, Alice, Medical), 
    (4, Jake, Social)
```

I want to query all record Ids of a specific type whose owners fall within a certain bounding box. Example: want all MEDICAL record Ids whose owners are within (36,-89) to (39,-88):

Here is my Solr query

```
q={!join+from=Username+to=UserName+fromIndex=Users}+(Location:[36.00,-89.00 TO 39.00,-88.00]) +(Category:Medical)
```

The error is: Category Field is undefined

If I repeat the same request with just Location, it returns empty result without an error.

I can tell that Location querying works since this call return all users that are needed:

```
q=Location:[36.00,-89.00 TO 39.00,-88.00]
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Catergory field undefined ? Is the field defined in schema.xml. Also i would prefer a filter query category:Medical for querying the results.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like that:

```
/solr/UserRecords/select/?q=Category:Medical&fq={!join+from=Username+to=UserName+fromIndex=Users}Location:[36.00,-89.00 TO 39.00,-88.00]
```

I'm assuming that you have 2 collections named "Users" and "UserRecords"

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be working well:

```
q=
{!join+from=id+to=Username+fromIndex=Users}             
{!geofilt+sfield=Location+pt=38.89,-77.03+d=5}
& fq=Category:Medical
```

It is not exactly a bounding box as previously requested, but a better approach

Comment: Care to explain how it's a better approach ? I am seeing the same problem with bbox!